# Try-Except: How to check a bool(true/false) as an exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to loop to ask a password until the user enters a valid password then break out of it.
How do I implement this method with a try/except? Is there a better way of doing this? I am a beginning so any help is appreciated!

```
def is_secure(s):
    # This function will check if the passed string s is a valid password
    # Return true if string is valid password
    # Returns false if string is not a valid password
    min_len = 6
    max_len = 15
    if len(s) < min_len or len(s) > max_len:
        return False
    else:
        return True



while True:
    try:
        password = str(input("Enter new password:"))
        if is_secure(password):
            print("Password is secure")
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("False")
    else:
        print("Password is insecure")
```

Comment: You can define a custom Exception by inheriting from Exception class and make it trigger if the password is not secure. Then you will be able to do it with `try-except`

Comment: "How do I implement this method with a try/except?" - *Why* implement this with try-except?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work:

```
while True:
  password = str(input("Enter new password:"))
  if is_secure(password):
      break
  print("Invalid password")
print("Password is secure")
```

You are trying to handle exceptions that are not thrown anywhere. Another solution would be to throw the exception, instead of printing "invalid password":

`raise Exception("Invalid password")`

Comment: Another way would be to raise the exception instead of returning `False` on is_secure.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should hopefully work.

```
class InsecurePasswordError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super().__init__(message)


class Password:
    def __init__(self, pwd: str):
        self.pwd = pwd

    @property
    def pwd(self):
        return self._pwd

    @pwd.setter
    def pwd(self, value):
        if len(value) <= 8:
            raise InsecurePasswordError('The length of the password is not sufficient!')
        elif .....:  # Add more conditions
             ....
        else:
            self._pwd = value


# And now in your code....
while True:
    try:
        i = input("Enter new password:")
        password = Password(i)
    except InsecurePasswordException as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        print("Password is secure")
```

Comment: Wow I no nowhere near your level but much appreciated